# Add semi-transparent overlay to activity backround at runtime

Tags: android, image, view

I have an app that i set the background to an image from xml. I get the view by calling

```
setContentView(R.)
```

.
How can i place a semi-transparent overlay on this background at runtime depending on a condition. I would like to have a red overlay with its alpha set to 50%.

I have tried creating a seperate xml file with the view duplicated and a different image/overlay but its messy as i have to inflate all the buttons/textview when i use the new view.

thanks matt

[edit1]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/carefreebgscaledlighting"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewcompanyname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#003F87" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewYouAreSignedIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#003F87"
         />

          <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewUnsentTransactions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewYouAreSignedIn"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#003F87"
         />
```

[edit2]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >


     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/transparentOverlay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/red_transparent" >


<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/carefreebgscaledlighting"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewcompanyname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#003F87" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewYouAreSignedIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#003F87"
         />
```

[edit3]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >



<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/carefreebgscaledlighting"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">




    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewcompanyname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#003F87" />
```

.

```
if(status.equalsIgnoreCase(IN)){

                youAreSignedInAt.setText("You are signed in at " + name);
                LinearLayout layout =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll1);
                layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.carefreebgscaledlightingred);
            }else{

                youAreSignedInAt.setText("You are not signed in");
                LinearLayout layout =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll1);
                layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.carefreebgscaledlighting);
            }
```

Comment: If you know how opaque you want it to be, why not a PNG?  This will be just one image you can add to the layout, whenever needed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you could declare the background color including alpha component in a resource file (i.e. colors.xml)

```
<color name="red_transparent">#66FF0000</color>
```

And then put a view (i.e. `RelativeLayout`), on top of the rest of the views.-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- All your views -->

    <!-- Transparent layer -->   
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/transparentOverlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/red_transparent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

All you need to do is changing visibility of R.id.transparentOverlay as you desire.

Comment: hi i've posted my xml. as you can see i have a drawable set as the background. is it possible to place a redish tint over this drawable at run time. is that what your code does? thanks

Comment: If you want the red overlay is on top of everything, including your drawable, yes, that's what's supposed to do my snippet. If you just want to apply a red filter to your drawable, that's a whole different story.

Comment: Still, if you want the red overlay just over the drawable, you could put @+id/transparentOverlay layout just above the view if the drawable.

Comment: Hi, i've placed the overlay above the drawable but it's not showing. edit2 shows this. Have you any ideas why or is that not what you meant? thanks.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself too well. To render the overlay `over` the drawable, you actually need to put it `under` it in your xml. Just move `transparentOverlay` between the `LinearLayout` with the background and the next `textviewcompanyname`.

Comment: hi, i've done it a diiferent way in edit3. I kept the original layout code but assigned an id to th LL layout. I created a second drawable with the alpha and red effects on it. I then switched the layout's drawable at runtime depending on a condition. thanks for your help though. Is the way i'm doing it now ok?

Comment: imho, there's nothing wrong with your solution. I'd just recommend using a `@color` instead of a `@drawable`, as is more versatile; you can dynamically change the `@color` value and transparency, and you save the resource space of the png drawable. Anyway, if you're not changing color nor transparency, your approach is perfectly fine to me.